# Embedding random variables in infinite-dimensional spaces

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, pr.probability, measure-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let $H$ be a reproducing kernel Hilbert space of functions $f:E\to F$ with kernel $k$. A point in $E$ may be embedded into $H$ via the canonical embedding $x\mapsto k(x,\cdot)$. Similarly, a random variable that takes values in $E$ defines a canonical $H$-valued random variable via the mapping $X\mapsto k(X, \cdot)$. Let $X_H := k(X, \cdot)$. Then $X_H$ "encodes" much of the information about $X$ via its mean and covariance operator. In particular, $X_H$ has properties that make it "nice" to deal with, e.g. it leads to nice calculations with means and covariances, and connects abstract covariance operators to the covariance of $X$. For example, it is not hard to show that if $C_X$ is the covariance operator of $X_H$, then 
$$
\text{cov}(f(X)) = \langle f, C_Xf\rangle.
$$

**My question:** Is there a similar construction that holds for *arbitrary* Hilbert spaces, or say even Banach spaces? Another way to think of this: Is there a way to embed $X$ into an RKHS $H$ that doesn't explicitly involve the kernel $k$ (but still leads to "nice" properties)?

(I am aware that one could define many different types of embeddings *ad hoc*, but my question is geared more towards whether or not there is a canonical way to do this that leads to something similar to $k(X,\cdot)$ and if so, what type of results are out there.)

Comment: I don't think I understand the construction you mention in the first paragraph.  Can you give precise definitions and statements, or a reference?

Comment: Hopefully fixed now. I shouldn't have referred to $X_H$ as an embedding into $H$, strictly speaking it embeds $X$ into the space of RVs over $H$.